# Close popup after email form is submitted

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Can anyone shed any light on this. . . . I'm trying to close an email opt-in popup upon clicking a 'submit' button. The pop up is using a WordPress plugin called arty popup. At present the popup has a close button that functions, plus there is an email address box and 'submit' button linked to a contact7 form plugin, which again works perfectly, on submitting an email address, at present the user will then have to use the pop up close button, rather than both action taking place on the one click.

apologies to post a lot of code, its only because I'm working with two plugins. Any pointers would be very welcome.

this is the pop up .php
    /*
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    this final section generates all the code that
    is displayed on the front-end of the WP Theme
    \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    */
    function arty_popup($args = array(), $content = null) {
    require 'inc/popup.php';    }

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'arty_header' );
function arty_header() { 
global $arty_settings;
$options = $arty_settings;?>
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"type="text  /javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("arty_popup_cookie1") <= 0) {

    loadPopupBox();
    }       


$('#wrap-out, #popupBoxClose').click( function() {
    unloadPopupBox();

    var c_name  =   'arty_popup_cookie';
    var value   =   'arty_popup_cookie1';
    var exdays  =   <?php echo $options['popup_cookie_time']; ?>;

     var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;

});

function unloadPopupBox() {
    $('#popup_box').fadeOut(200);
    $("#wrap-out").css({    
        "display": "none"  
    }); 
}

function loadPopupBox() {
    $('#popup_box').fadeIn(200);
    $("#wrap-out").css({
        "background": "#000",
        "opacity": "0.7"  
    });         
}


});
```

the pop up button .css

```
.btn{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width:91px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    border:none;
    background:url(images/btn.gif) no-repeat top;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

the contact7 form .php

```
<?php
/**
** A base module for [submit]
**/

/* Shortcode handler */

add_action( 'init', 'wpcf7_add_shortcode_submit', 5 );

function wpcf7_add_shortcode_submit() {
wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'submit', 'wpcf7_submit_shortcode_handler' );}

function wpcf7_submit_shortcode_handler( $tag ) {
$tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

$class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );

$atts = array();

$atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
$atts['id'] = $tag->get_option( 'id', 'id', true );
$atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'int', true );

$value = isset( $tag->values[0] ) ? $tag->values[0] : '';

    if ( empty( $value ) )
        $value = __( 'Send', 'wpcf7' );

$atts['type'] = 'submit';
$atts['value'] = $value;

$atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

$html = sprintf( '<input %1$s />', $atts );

return $html;}


/* Tag generator */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpcf7_add_tag_generator_submit', 55 );

    function wpcf7_add_tag_generator_submit() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wpcf7_add_tag_generator' ) )
        return;

    wpcf7_add_tag_generator( 'submit', __( 'Submit button', 'wpcf7' ),
        'wpcf7-tg-pane-submit', 'wpcf7_tg_pane_submit', array( 'nameless' => 1 ) );
}

function wpcf7_tg_pane_submit( &$contact_form ) {?>
<div id="wpcf7-tg-pane-submit" class="hidden">
<form action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td><code>id</code> (<?php echo esc_html( __( 'optional', 'wpcf7' ) ); ?>)<br />
<input type="text" name="id" class="idvalue oneline option" /></td>

<td><code>class</code> (<?php echo esc_html( __( 'optional', 'wpcf7' ) ); ?>)<br />
<input type="text" name="class" class="classvalue oneline option" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Label', 'wpcf7' ) ); ?> (<?php echo esc_html( __( 'optional', 'wpcf7' ) ); ?>)<br />
<input type="text" name="values" class="oneline" /></td>

<td></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="tg-tag"><?php echo esc_html( __( "Copy this code and paste it into the form left.", 'wpcf7' ) ); ?><br /><input type="text" name="submit" class="tag"readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.select()" /></div>
</form>
</div>
<?php}?>
```

Comment: That's lot of code to post here mate. Try to simplify it and you will success more on getting answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
$('#wrap-out, #popupBoxClose').click( function() {
```

to

```
$('#wrap-out, #popupBoxClose, #popup_box [type="submit"]').click( function() {
```

This adds the click handler that closes the popup box to the submit button for the form, so that the popup box will close on submit.